# Why there is no double-render when using before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering why there is no double-render when there is a `redirect_to` or `render` in `before_action`. Consider this example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
 before_action :callback

 def new
  callback2
  render 'new'
 end

 def callback
  render 'new'
 end

 def callback2
  render 'new'
 end

end
```

I see that `before_action` will be useless if it can't redirect but how it is made? If I comment the `before_action` it will throw exception.
How is `before_action` implemented to not cause double-render?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question properly, but if I do, there is no double-render because nothing has been rendered yet.  I believe `before_action` is changing what will be rendered.

Comment: If you set callback :before_action then this is called before loading an action so in your code when you call it, callback render 'new' before loading your new action, I am using loading word to understand it better

Comment: How can I implement my own `before_action`? I've put the example with `callback2` to illustrate that without `before_action` there will be double-render.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See the [Rails Guide on controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) :

> If a "before" filter renders or redirects, the action will not run. If there are additional filters scheduled to run after that filter, they are also cancelled.